# Как эти две строки написать на чистом javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

хочу переделать jQuery строкb на JS.

**ПЕРВЫЙ ВОПРОС:**

Есть такая функция:

```
//показываю содержимое корзины
function showMiniCart(){
    var out ='';
    for (var w in cart){
        out += w + ' --- '+cart[w]+'<br>';
    }
    out+='<br><a href="cart.html">Корзина</a>';
    $('#mini-cart').html(out);                          
}
```

Хотел перевети эту строку:

`$('#mini-cart').html(out);`

на сайте:
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#matches_selector

есть перевод:

`$(el).html();  на чистом js:   el.innerHTML`

Я попробовал перевести:
`document.getElementById("#mini-cart").innerHTML`

Но в скобках у меня еще переменная out, которую я обьявил раньше в своем большом коде, я так понимаю в скобках то что выводится на страницу, но куда вложить "out"? Если после innerHTML нет скобок.
Может так:

`document.getElementById("#mini-cart").innerHTML="out";`

### праивльно?

**ВТОРОЙ ВОПРОС:**

```
function addToCart() {

var articul = $(this).attr('data-art'); 

///...здесь код условия if-else

localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart) );
showMiniCart();
}
```

Хотел перевети эту строку:

`var articul = $(this).attr('data-art');`

на сайте:
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#matches_selector

есть перевод:

`$(el).attr('tabindex', 3);  на чистом JS:    el.setAttribute('tabindex', 3);`

но у меня есть "this", его просто вписать вместо "el"? И нет второго аргумента(я не знаю что это за аргумент) , поэтому я не знаю как правильно переделать. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: "но куда вложить "out"? Если после innerHTML нет скобок." --- так вы откройте документацию javascript и посмотрите что можно сделать с этим  innerHTML (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). А то до http://youmightnotneedjquery. добрались, а до документации, почему-то, нет

Comment: по второму вопросу - нужен не setAttribute, а getAttribute. А чем заменить $(this) - нужно весь код посмотреть откуда он прилетает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showMiniCart(){
  var out ='';
  for (var w in cart){
    out += w + ' --- ' + cart[w] + '<br>';
  }
  out+='<br><a href="cart.html">Корзина</a>';
  document.getElementById('mini-cart').innerHTML = out;
  // или document.querySelector('#mini-cart');                    
}
```

.

```
function addToCart() {

  var articul = this.getAttribute('data-art'); 
             // this.dataset.art;

  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart) );
  showMiniCart();
}
```

P.s.

• Эти создают / меняют атрибут (после написанного кода, у элемента будет `data-bubu="100500"`)

jQ: `$('#bubu').attr('data-bubu', 100500);`

JS: `document.querySelector('#bubu').setAttribute('data-bubu', 100500);`

• А эти - получают значение этого атрибута (и, например, сохраняют в переменную):

jQ: `var moo = $('#bubu').attr('data-bubu');`

JS: `var moo = document.querySelector('#bubu').getAttribute('data-bubu');`

P.s.-2 можете где-то посмотреть про разницу attr() и prop()... и разницу атрибутов и свойств)